# Inter-cluster variance

Tags: clustering, variance, definition, manova

Can you please help me understand how is inter-cluster (between clusters) variance defined? As opposed to intra-cluster variance which is pretty straightforward, I have not managed to found a clear answer myself.

Comment: These are the core definitions of MANOVA (clusters are k groups). Please read about it. Total scatter matrix minus pooled (summed) within-group scatter matrix is the between group scatter matrix. Trace of of it, divided by `N-k`, is the between-groups variance. It is the same as computing means for the groups and weight each mean by the number of points in the group, and then compute the variance.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks for the comment. Is it simply $\frac{\sum_{i}^{K}n_{i}||c_{i}-\bar{x}||^{2}}{K}$, where $\bar{x}$ is global mean and $c_i$ is i-th cluster centroid?

Answer (score 1):

Inter-cluster variance is defined almost identical to intra-cluster variance.

The difference is that you don't calculate the variance between all the samples within a single cluster but you take each cluster's centroid (typically the mean of all samples within a cluster) and calculate the variance between all centroids.